# Nonexistence of a real analytic function

Tags: functional-analysis, real-analysis, complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

My question is:

Suppose $f$ is a real analytic function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\|f\|_\infty=1$. $$S=\cup_{k=1}^d l_k,$$ here $$l_k=\Big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d| x=(0,\cdots,x^k,0\cdots,0),\  x_k\in\mathbb{R} \ \mbox{is the}\ k\mbox{-coordinate}\ \Big\}.$$ If we know, 
$$f|_S\equiv 1.$$
Can we get $f\equiv1$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Thank you a lot if you can give me any comment or reference.

Comment: Let me understand this ... for example, a real-analytic function defined in the plane that is identically 1 on both of the coordinate axes, must be identically 1 everywhere?  There may be some confusion since you use both $x_k$ and $x^k$ in your formulation...

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(x) = 1 - \prod_k \sin^2(x_k)$?